# Kubuntu : Plasma global theme doesn't change the application style

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes

Only built in themes are working properly in my fresh Kubuntu 22.04 install.
When I change the global theme (to a downloaded one from 'Get new global themes'), it merely changes the window decorations and icons. But Plasma style and application styles (and everything else, I think) remains unchanged. I tried manually adding the plasma style. But I couldn't figure out a way to manually load a application style.
I did a fresh install of Kubuntu on a friend's PC a few days ago and it didn't have any problem like this. I used the same bootable USB on both occasions.
I'm really new to KDE and qt so if anyone could suggest a way to fix this it would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Edit : If you need any additional information, just let me know.